# How do pixels in a LCD display are individually controlled by a electrode?

Tags: transistors, led, diodes, display, transistor-array

How do tiny subpixels in the Led displays are controlled by those indium tin oxide electrode.How do they provide different voltage for each pixel

Comment: Via DACs maybe?

Comment: Will you please elaborate i mean how that one layer of ITO can give different voltage to each pixel to control its intensity

Comment: It works exactly like DRAM except with an analog current level

Comment: ITO is conductive and transparent. If you "build" the substrate on it then you can use it as either anode or cathode. The only difference is there's no copper or any other metal based traces. And if you apply different voltage levels or drive currents (e.g. via DACs for digital applications) then you'll get different brightness levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have Row Drivers (the high voltage drivers that clock the gate of the FET switches) and the Column Drivers that provide the precision voltages (including transfer curve gamma shaping for good whites and good blacks) to control the amount of polarization.

Together, each pixel's R/G/B has private switching.

Comment: So you mean each pixel is connected to row and coloum drivers to drive individual pixel.But how they are connected to the drivers is the question how can we connect millions of pixel using wires and if we say  that they are connected By ITO then how do you individually control voltage for each pixel.There will be some sort of printed layer that connects the pixels to the drivers.

Comment: If you have 2,000 columns, then the display will have 6,000 vertical conductors to bring in the 2,000 RGB voltages from the DACs in the Column Drivers. If you have 1,000 rows, then you have 6,000 * 1,000 = 6,000,000 thin-film slow-mobility FETS, with their gates controlled by the Row Drivers (30 volt swings in the older panels, 10 volts in new panels.)

Comment: I watched a video in which a guy was showing display at microscopic level and all those tft transistors and other are printed on a think transparent film.Is it true for other display types also like Ips or Oled.Where TFT are driving those individual pixels